# How to delete a wrong post

Tags: discussion, support, off-topic

I posted [this](https://superuser.com/questions/1272628/why-do-people-expend-signifcant-effort-on-pirating-the-works-of-others-for-free) off-topic post on Super User.

And now I am stuck with it. I can't delete it. Other people see it and downvote which causes me to lose reputation and puts me at risk of being blocked from asking questions. Please Help!

Comment: Deletion is also a criteria for question blocks

Comment: From our [question deletion help page](https://superuser.com/help/deleted-questions) you can only self-delete it if the question "has zero answers" or "only one answer, but that answer has no upvotes". In your case you had a single upvoted answer blocking you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You've got two questions that aren't on topic, and deletions are *also* one of the criteria for question blocks. Your association bonus *ought* to be a bit of a cushion, but no one really knows the question block criteria.

I'd start you [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers-from-th). While I typically suggest the [help center](https://superuser.com/help) and [tour](https://superuser.com/tour) on the main site, consider your own questions as well. They're off topic (consider the scope of the site. Your questions are about *people* or are opinion based.). Your writing style is a little odd, showing both a knowledge and a lack of proper formatting.

Your next question ought to be about a problem *you* have faced *relating* to a *computer*. Its worth considering "why are my questions being closed?" and "How can I ask better questions" as much as "how do I keep posting here?".

I quote the [hotdog vendor to the buddist monk](https://www.reddit.com/r/Jokes/comments/1r2xom/a_buddhist_monk_walks_up_to_a_hot_dog_stand/?st=janjwfl1&sh=fb33613e) when I say... change must come from within. Making previous mistakes 'go away' is less important and doing it right the next time.

Comment: Thanks brother! you have cleaned all the mess. I will take care from the next time